# Get rid of ^@ in vim output from system(...)

Tags: vim

I am trying to add the result of a `system()` call as a header for one of the plugins I use (vim-startify). The command is:

```
system('vim --version | head -1')
```

However when it gets printed it has an extra character in the end: `^@`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 12 2017 23:20:57)^@
```

[image]

There is a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/75130/how-to-remove-this-symbol-with-vim), but it addresses a file, not a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
system('vim --version | head -1 | tr -d "\n"')
```

See `$ man tr`.

Answer (score 2):

Just chomp it: `system('whatever')[:-2]`, or, if you prefer something more robust—something that won't misbehave should the newline be missing— you can apply: `substitute(system_result, "\n\\+$", "", "")`.

Note that, unlike `tr`, this solution works on all platforms. That's what we used to do with the `chomp()` function in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

With Vim 8 (or late 7.4 versions):

```
get(systemlist('vim --version'), 0)
```

Comment: We don't exactly need `get()` as `systemlist()` will always return something. `systemlist('vim --version')[0]`  would have been enough. Anyway, it's nice to know that `systemlist()` chomps trailing newline. Thanks.

Comment: _`systemlist()` will always return something._ - Unless it returns the empty list, for whatever reason.  Then `...[0]` is an error. :)

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking of this particular case (either `vim` isn't found, or `vim --version` should return something). You're perfectly right in the general case.