# how to pipe a shell command output into a vim function?

Tags: vim

I am using [vim-test](https://github.com/janko-m/vim-test)
and I am trying to build a test strategy that uses MakeGreen plugin.

The command is `:TestFile | MakeGreen()` which works, but here is the issue.

```
function! MakeGreenStrategy(cmd) abort
  execute '!'.a:cmd " this is a shell command which I would like to pipe into a vim function called MakeGreen()
endfunction
```

so what is right way of piping the output of a shell command into a vim function like the first command but in a vimscript function.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`system()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29).

Note: you'll want to trim the trailing newline. See [Get rid of ^@ in vim output from system(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326732/get-rid-of-in-vim-output-from-system)

Comment: thank you, but `system` does not allow me to call TestFile which is a vim function (and that function calls is the one that makes the shell command).

Comment: The output of that shell command is what I am trying to pipe back again into vim function , so this works from vim's ex mode `:TestFile | MakeGreen`.

Comment: You can't use the bar (`:h bar`) to pipe commands in vim command line. You would have to think about another character that the first vim user command will interpret. Otherwise, what you can do is `:echo somevimfunction(systemlist('external command'))`.